# Send data to Azure Event Hubs and forward it to Azure Data Explorer in dynamic tables

Tags: c++, rest, azure-eventhub, azure-data-explorer

We have a C++ agent that runs on a large number of endpoints (>200,000) and sends the data to a backend (e.g. Splunk). This generates data of approx. 20-30 MB per day per endpoint.
The data is divided in such a way that it is logically grouped. E.g. inventory or performance data. These are to be stored in different tables in Azure Data Explorer.
One table per logical grouping. The schema for these tables was created in advance. We are talking about a total of around 70 tables. The table with the most data generates more than half of the data volume.

We are currently checking how integration into Azure Data Explorer can work. As Azure Data Explorer has a limit of 4 GB per hour per table (queued ingestion 6 GB),
a direct connection to Azure Data Explorer is probably out of the question here.
We therefore use the detour via Azure Event Hubs.

In the Azure Data Explorer, I have set up a connection to Event Hubs, which has defined a fixed table as the target and fetches the data automatically.
Sending the data to this table via REST API works fine. Authentication is done via JWT token.

I would now like to send the data to Azure Event Hubs so that it is automatically written to different tables in Azure Data Explorer.
Preferably in CSV format.
According to the documentation, there are ingestion properties (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-data-event-hub-overview#event-hubs-properties) that specify the target table. However, this only seems to work if the data is sent directly to Azure Data Explorer.

How can I send the data to Azure Event Hubs so that it is automatically stored in Azure Data Explorer in different tables?

I've tried the KQL query:
`.ingest inline into table LicenseInfo json '` 
`{`   
`"tableName": "LicenseInfo",`   
`"rows": [`
     `{`
         `"Time": 1701079234,`
         `"LicensingState": "State",`
         `"LicenseCountTotal": 123,`
         `"MaintenanceEnd": "2024-12-31"`
     `}`
   `]`
`}`
`'`
which works fine (in Azure Data Explorer).

When I send the same command to Azure Event Hubs, I get an ingestion error:

`BadRequest_InvalidBlob: hr: '2161770525' 'Syntax at character 0'`

Comment: please refer to this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/data-explorer/ingest-data/data-explorer-ingest-event-hub-portal) for ingesting data from Event Hub into Azure Synapse Data Explorer

Comment: Aren't these two different Azure services (Azure Synapse Analytics and Azure Data Explorer)? Or is what we have in mind not possible with Azure Data Explorer?

Comment: Yes, we have Azure Synapse Analytics and Azure Data Explorer Clusters. Refer this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-data-event-hub-overview) for  Azure Data [Explorer](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-data-explorer-blog/azure-stream-analytics-no-code-editor-for-adx/ba-p/3696718#:~:text=In%20the%20Azure%20portal%2C%20go%20to%20your%20Event,out%20your%20ADX%20cluster%20parameters%20and%20hit%20connect).

Comment: the data format should be like this while [sending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76213232/data-is-not-visible-in-azure-data-explorer-after-ingestion-from-event-hub)

Answer (score 1):

Steps for ingesting data from Event Hub into Azure Synapse Data [Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/data-explorer/ingest-data/data-explorer-ingest-event-hub-portal):

**Create a Data Explorer Pool:**

[image]

**Create a Target Table:**

Create a JSON mapping for the table:

```json
.create table TestTable ingestion json mapping 'TestMapping' '[{"column":"TimeStamp", "Properties": {"Path": "$.timeStamp"}},{"column":"Name", "Properties": {"Path":"$.name"}} ,{"column":"Metric", "Properties": {"Path":"$.metric"}}, {"column":"Source", "Properties": {"Path":"$.source"}}]'
```

**Create an Event Hub:**

[image]

- Identity used for authentication and configure networking settings in Event Hub.

**Connect to Event Hub from Data Explorer:**

- In Synapse Studio, under the Data Explorer pool, select Databases > TestDatabase.
- Select Data connections and Add data connection.
  [image]
- Create a data connection with the Event Hub details.

**Configure Target Table:**

- Set routing settings for ingesting data (static routing):

  - Table name: TestTable
  - Data format: JSON
  - Mapping: TestMapping
- Code reference is taken from [MSDOC](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-cpp/blob/main/sdk/eventhubs/azure-messaging-eventhubs/README.md).

[image]

```json
TestTable | count
TestTable
```